# Why don't complex-number literals work in clang?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, complex-numbers, user-defined-literals

When I run this code [on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/HdviA2), it prints `(2,3)`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main() {
    std::complex<double> val = 2 + 3i;
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I use clang on macOS 10.11.6, I get no errors or warnings, but the output is  `(2,0)`:

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0

$ clang -lc++ test.cpp && ./a.out
(2,0)
```

What happened to the imaginary part? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://ideone.com/RbQDU6) with clang?

Comment: Just did. Same result.

Comment: Shouldn't the Clang compile command be `clang++ -std=c++14`?

Comment: Interesting. `-std=c++14` triggers the error `no matching literal operator for call to 'operator""i' ...`. Why on earth would it compile without this?

Comment: @jtbandes user-defined literals as a *language* feature were part of C++11. Literal operators for string, chrono, complex were put into the *library* for C++14.  So the C++11 compiler knew `3i` was a user-defined literal but was unable to find a `operator""i(unsigned long long n)` in any library.

Comment: @emsr that's not exactly the reason. It didn't know `3i` was a user-defined literal, but it treated it as a `_Complex` value from a GNU extension. See my comments on the answer below.

Comment: @jtbandes  Ah. That's a nasty cross-version gotcha that I've been hit by.  Arithmetic will work for C++14 but not C++11.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe for this first example the compiler is using a GNU extension:

```
-fext-numeric-literals (C++ and Objective-C++ only)
```

> Accept imaginary, fixed-point, or machine-defined literal number
>   suffixes as GNU extensions. When this option is turned off these
>   suffixes are treated as C++11 user-defined literal numeric suffixes.
>   This is on by default for all pre-C++11 dialects and all GNU dialects:
>   -std=c++98, -std=gnu++98, -std=gnu++11, -std=gnu++14. This option is off by default for ISO C++11 onwards (-std=c++11, ...).

When I run it with clang I get (are you using `-Wall -pedantic`? :)):

> warning: imaginary constants are a GNU extension
>   [-Wgnu-imaginary-constant]

Either way, your code is not standard compliant. To use C++14 literals make the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
using namespace std::complex_literals;
int main() {
    std::complex<double> val = 2.0 + 3i;
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

From the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%22%22i):

> These operators are declared in the namespace
>   std::literals::complex_literals, where both literals and
>   complex_literals are inline namespaces. **Access to these operators can
>   be gained with using namespace std::literals, using namespace
>   std::complex_literals, and using namespace
>   std::literals::complex_literals.**

Comment: Ah, I should have thought to fiddle with warning flags... indeed, enabling -Weverything gives me `warning: imaginary constants are a GNU extension`, and even more importantly `warning: implicit conversion discards imaginary component`. It's frustrating that this warning wouldn't be on by default...

Comment: @jtbandes: I see, the imaginary part is getting thrown out by the implicit conversion to int. Lesson learned here is to `always compile at the highest warning level possible`. This is true for all compiled languages.